# Optimize a query

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-performance

How can I proceed to make my response time more faster, approximately the average time of response is 0.2s ( 8039 records in my items table & 81 records in my tracking table )

**Query**

```
 SELECT a.name, b.cnt  FROM `items` a  LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT guid, COUNT(*) cnt FROM tracking WHERE
date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 day ) GROUP BY guid)  b ON
a.`id` = b.guid WHERE a.`type` = 'streaming' AND a.`state` = 1 
ORDER BY b.cnt DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 75
```

**Tracking table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `tracking` (
`id` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`guid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`ip` int(11) NOT NULL,
`date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `i1` (`ip`,`guid`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4303 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Items table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`guid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`embed` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`description` text,
`tags` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`vote_val_total` float DEFAULT '0',
`vote_total` float(11,0) DEFAULT '0',
`rate` float DEFAULT '0',
`icon` text CHARACTER SET ascii,
`state` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9258 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: You could start by adding an actual JOIN condition (WHERE a.column = b.column) on the tables.

Comment: also, using `date` as a field is probably asking for trouble. For instance, I suspect that without ticks, as it's written, that query simply isn't going to work.

Comment: Please read this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 Then, please [edit] your question to give more details.  Also, pro tip, don't use `SELECT *` in queries with JOINs in them, and certainly not in queries with GROUP BY in them.

Comment: So what i can use for replace SELECT * ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query, as written, doesn't make much sense. It produces all possible combinations of rows in your two tables and then groups them.

You may want this:

```
    SELECT a.*, b.cnt 
      FROM `items` a  
 LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT guid, COUNT(*) cnt 
                FROM tracking 
               WHERE `date` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 day) 
            GROUP BY guid
           )  b ON a.guid = b.guid
  ORDER BY b.cnt DESC
```

The high-volume data in this query come from the relatively large tracking table. So, you should add a compound index to it, using the columns `(date, guid)`.  This will allow your query to random-access the index by `date` and then scan it for `guid` values.

```
 ALTER TABLE tracking ADD INDEX guid_summary (`date`, guid);
```

I suppose you'll see a nice performance improvement.

**Pro tip:** Don't use `SELECT *`. Instead, give a list of the columns you want in your result set. For example,

```
SELECT a.guid, a.name, a.description, b.cnt
```

Why is this important?

First, it makes your software more resilient against somebody adding columns to your tables in the future.

Second, it tells the MySQL server to sling around only the information you want. That can improve performance really dramatically, especially when your tables get big.

Comment: nice answer -- another important point -- 8000 records is not big.

Comment: I have create the index in my tracking table and remove the * for specify the columns i want to retrieve , i have a response time of 0,17 ms possible to reduce ? x)

Comment: 170 microseconds?  That's reasonably fast.

Answer (score 0):

Since `tracking` has significantly fewer rows than `items`, I will propose the following.

```
SELECT  i.name, c.cnt
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  guid, COUNT(*) cnt
            FROM  tracking
            WHERE  date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 day )
            GROUP BY  guid 
    ) AS c
    JOIN  items AS i  ON i.id = c.guid
    WHERE  i.type = 'streaming'
      AND  i.state = 1;
    ORDER BY  c.cnt DESC
    LIMIT  15 OFFSET 75
```

It will fail to display any items for which `cnt` is 0.  (Your version displays the items with `NULL` for the count.)

Composite indexes needed:

```
items: The PRIMARY KEY(id) is sufficient.
tracking: INDEX(date, guid) -- "covering"
```

Other issues:

- If `ip` is an IP-address, it needs to be `INT UNSIGNED`.  But that covers only IPv4, not IPv6.
- It seems like `date` is not just a "date", but really a date+time.  Please rename it to avoid confusion.
- `float(11,0)` -- Don't use `FLOAT` for integers.  Don't use `(m,n)` on `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.  `INT UNSIGNED` makes more sense here.

`OFFSET` is naughty when it comes to performance -- it must scan over the skipped records.  But, in your query, there is no way to avoid collecting *all* the possible rows, sorting them, stepping over 75, and only finally delivering 15 rows.  (And, with no more than 81, it won't be a full 15.)

What version are you using?  There have been important changes to the Optimization of `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... )`.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT` for each query under discussion.